# Using the Join command to eliminate extra paragraph breaks

Tags: python, join, strip

So I have this text:

```
 '
 Location
 Address

 Number

 Website
'
```

Except the top and bottom lines are empty as well, there aren't single quotes on those two lines. I basically want to make sure each line is one after another without any line breaks. This is what I would like it to look like.

```
 Location
 Address
 Number
 Website
```

I want to strip all of the line breaks and just have each result one line after another. This is the code to scrape the information from a webpage.

```
results = soup.findAll('div', class_='name')
for each in results:
    worksheet.write(row,1,each.text)
    row += 1
```

Each time I run through this, I want the results to print one line after another. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use a simple `if`?

```
results = soup.findAll('div', class_='name')
for each in results:
    if each.text:
        worksheet.write(row,1,each.text)
        row += 1
```

Comment: The output is still the same. There are still paragraph breaks in the cell with the information.

Comment: My guess is that `each.text` is not really blank.  It might be a string of blanks.  Try `if each.text.strip():` instead.

Comment: There is it. I was wondering why the first solution wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To join the results with a line-break use :

```
('\n').join(results)
```

To join with new lines and remove any new line present use :

```
import re
line=re.sub(r"(\n)+",r"\n",('\n').join(results))
```

The above case is useful if you don't know how many new lines exist between the text.(reduces multiple newlines to one)

Also the answer given by Malvolio is to avoid the blank line while writing:

```
if each.text:
```

This line would check if a line(`each` in your case) has text, if it doesn't it skips the statements below it.

Comment: Good to know it helped :)